# Re-ordering columns in pandas dataframe based on column date

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

how to sort the pandas pivot table header in the order of month and year not alphabets order?

the current order is in alphabet order based on the name of the month, i'd like to be in the order of month and year

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the time to read this post on [how to provide a great pandas example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) as well as how to provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and revise your question accordingly. These tips on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) may also be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to simulate your problem and have this solution. Here, I have a data set with two columns (YearMonth and Sales) and sort the data on YearMonth column before pivot the data. The sort help us to have YearMonth columns in a required order after pivot. Please check the below given code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame([[201801,2000.00],[201809,4000.00],[201803,10000.00],[201806,12000.00],[201802,20000.00],[201811,2000.00]],columns=['YearMonth','Sales'])
print('Original data:')
print(data)

data = data.sort_values(by=['YearMonth'])
print('Sort data on Year Month column:')
print(data)

print('Pivot data:')
print(data.pivot(columns='YearMonth',values=['Sales']))
```

**Output: Original data**

```
   YearMonth    Sales
0     201801   2000.0
1     201809   4000.0
2     201803  10000.0
3     201806  12000.0
4     201802  20000.0
5     201811   2000.0
```

**Sort data on Year Month column:**

```
   YearMonth    Sales
0     201801   2000.0
4     201802  20000.0
2     201803  10000.0
3     201806  12000.0
1     201809   4000.0
5     201811   2000.0
```

**Pivot data:**

```
            Sales                                           
YearMonth  201801   201802   201803   201806  201809  201811
0          2000.0      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
1             NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN  4000.0     NaN
2             NaN      NaN  10000.0      NaN     NaN     NaN
3             NaN      NaN      NaN  12000.0     NaN     NaN
4             NaN  20000.0      NaN      NaN     NaN     NaN
5             NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN     NaN  2000.0
```

Hope, this may help you to resolve your problem.

Comment: Thanks a lllooootttttttt! it works perfectly well for me :D